# How do I model CNN that splits into 4 different GMP,GAP layers

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to recreate these four CNN models.

[image]

I don't understand what is happening at the layer where it splits off into 4 layers. That is what the author refers to as 3rd part. I am not sure what is happening when it is concatenated together either. I am trying to model this using PyTorch.

The author describes the model in the following two ways.

> In CNNs, one of the most important concepts is the hierarchical
> convolutional data processing, which was introduced by Kunihiko
> Fukushima [61] and then developed by Lecun et al. in the LeNet-
> 5 architecture [62]. For the development of the CNN, the archi-
> tectures are getting deeper. Because the information is abstracted
> layer by layer, researchers tend to use smaller convolutional filters,
> such as 1 × 1 and 3 × 3, and more stacked layers rather than bigger
> filters taking into account the computational costs and learning ca-
> pacity of the architecture. Thus, in the first and third parts of each
> architecture, the size of convolutional kernels was set to 3 × 3.

Also,

> The third parts of the four architectures are the same. This part
> consists of two global-max-pooling (GMP) layers and two global-
> average-pooling (GAP) layers following three convolution layers
> and a max-pooling layer.

Here is the [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231219306447?via%3Dihub) to the original paper. I suspect it is a hierarchical model, but I am not sure how I would implement this. Would I use pyTorch.nn parallel container? I can't find documentation on this [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#containers), but [this](https://nn.readthedocs.io/en/rtd/containers/index.html#parallel) seems relevant.

I have this so far.

```
class first_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(first_model, self).__init__()
        self.stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=4, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3,3)),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=(3,3)),
            nn.Dropout()
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3,3)),
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(1,1),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Conv3d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3,3),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return
```

Comment: Is it simply slicing the 128 channels into four 32-channels and applying those filters there? If so, how does concat work?